# Difference between database name wrapped in single quotes and not wrapped

Tags: php, mysql

```
$createPersonTable_SQL = "CREATE TABLE ".$db['database'].".Person ( ";
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= "ID INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , ";
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= "FirstName VARCHAR( 50 ) , ";
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= "LastName VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL , ";
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= "Sex VARCHAR( 4 ) NOT NULL , ";
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= "Age INT( 3 ) NOT NULL , ";
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= "Job VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL , ";
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= "Height float( 2) NOT NULL , ";
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= "Weight float( 2 ) NOT NULL , ";
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= "Hobby VARCHAR( 1000 ) NOT NULL , ";
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= "Salary FLOAT( 2 ) NOT NULL ";
    $createPersonTable_SQL .= ")";
```

For the first line, if I run the part of the php code like this, table is created successfully. But if I change the first line to 
                    `"CREATE TABLE '".$db['database']."'.Person ( ";`           table is created unsuccessfully. Can anyone explain why one version works but the other one doesn't. I run the code using xampp. Thanks!

Comment: table name should not be encoded by `'` or `"`.

Comment: sensible subject lines please

Comment: You can't enclose identifiers with `'` or `"`. You have to use backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database name cannot be wrapped into single quotes in mysql. You can use backtick if you need to:

```
$createPersonTable_SQL = "CREATE TABLE `".$db['database']."`.Person ( ";
```